# How this variable works

Tags: coding-style, less

I am trying to wrap my head around how programming languages work. Sometimes I come across things that stump me. I was wondering if anyone can explain how the code below works.

This is from http://lesscss.org/#docs

```
It is also possible to define variables with a variable name:

@fnord: "I am fnord.";
@var: 'fnord';
content: @@var;

Which compiles to:

content: "I am fnord.";
```

In my untrained mind @@var would equal "fnord fnord" or "I am fnord. fnord"

Please can anyone explain how content is equal to "I am fnord" Thanks

Comment: Hi, no I haven't I was on lesscss.org reading up about it when I saw this. I figured it was just something I couldn't wrap my head around because I'm such a noob. I didn't think it might be wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when parsing @@var, you evaluate @var first, it gives you fnord, then @@var continues to be evaluated as @fnord and @fnord value is "I am fnord.". It's kinda dirty to allow that as a programming language, but PHP does for example...